# CGAL: Output from neighbour when the triangle has none

Tags: c++, return-value, cgal

So I am wondering what happens in CGAL Delaunay triangulation when you call the neighbor function for a neighbor that doesn't exist. In the documentation ([HERE](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/TDS_2_ref/Concept_TriangulationDataStructure_2--Face.html#Cross_link_anchor_1366)) it says this:

```
The neighbor with index i is the neighbor which is opposite to the vertex with index i.

Face_handle  f.neighbor ( int i) const   //returns the neighbor i of f.
                                        //Precondition:     0 ≤ i ≤ 2.
```

But not all triangles can have 3 neighbors. Edge and corner triangles will neighbor only 2. Given that it must now return a Face_handle, what would happen for the neighbors that don't exist? Maybe it will be NULL? How can i check this?

The reason i am looking to do this is because i would like to identify all the edge triangles in a Delaunay triangulation. Being able to check for triangles with 2 or less neighbors would be very useful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you are talking of "edge and corner triangles", I believe you need to re-read the documentation of CGAL to see what they call a triangulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Triangulation_2/Chapter_main.html).

CGAL introduces an *infinite vertex*, hence each "border edge" has an additional neighbour,  which is an infinite triangle composed of the two vertices of your edge and the infinite vertex.

Comment: Awesome, now is there a way to test for a neighbor with an infinite vertex? Or is it a matter of looping through each of a triangles neighbors and looking at the vertices to see if they are infinite?

Comment: @Ben See the first example code on the link above. The infinite vertex is accessible with `myTriangulation.infinite_vertex()` , so you can check if a given face contains it or not.

Comment: Thanks, the better solution is that the triangulation type has a check for infinite faces so i can just go: `delaunay.is_infinite(face_iterator->neighbor(0))` to check each face surrounding a triangle. Your help has been excellent.

Comment: @Ben Oh ok great! Glad that I've been helpful.